# Unable to type in text box when passing onChange prop from parent to child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have a parent component which holds state that maintains what is being typed in an input box. However, I am unable to type anything in my input box. The input box is located in my child component, and the onChange and value of the input box is stored in my parent component.

Is there any way I can store all the form logic/input data on my parent component and just access it through my child components?

Here is a section of my parent component code:

```
export class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      screenType: 'init',
      series: [],
      isLoading: true,
      title: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.searchAPI = this.searchAPI.bind(this);
    this.clickSeries = this.clickSeries.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
    });
  }
  onKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      this.searchAPI();
    }
  };
  async searchAPI() {
    ...some search function
  } 
  render() {
      return (
        <Init onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} search={this.searchAPI} />
      );
}
```

And here is a section of my Child component:

```
function Init(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="search-container-init">
          <input
            onKeyPress={props.onKeyPress}
            className="searchbar-init"
            type="text"
            value={props.value}
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            placeholder="search for a TV series"></input>
          <button className="btn-init" onClick={props.search}>
            search
          </button>                       
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Init;
```

Comment: Please change  onChange={props.handleChange} in your child component to  onChange={(e) => { props.handleChange(e) } }

Comment: In parent component change your handleChange function and change this.setState({ value: e.target.value }) to this.setState({ value: e })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect function name used in the child. `onChange` prop passed into child in the parent and using that in the child as `handleChange`.

Also, you do not need to bind explicitly if using ES6 function definition.

Here is the updated code:

Search.js

```
export class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      screenType: 'init',
      series: [],
      isLoading: true,
      title: '',
    };
  }
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
    });
  }
  const onKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      this.searchAPI();
    }
  };
  const async searchAPI = () => {
    ...some search function
  } 
  render() {
      return (
        <Init onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} value={this.state.value} handleChange={this.handleChange} search={this.searchAPI} />
      );
}
```

Child component:

```
function Init(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="search-container-init">
          <input
            onKeyPress={props.onKeyPress}
            className="searchbar-init"
            type="text"
            value={props.value}
            onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e)}
            placeholder="search for a TV series"></input>
          <button className="btn-init" onClick={props.search}>
            search
          </button>                       
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Init;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your child component, you are using props.handleChange! But in your parent component, you passed it as onChange! Use the same name you used to pass the value/func. It should be like props.onChange! A silly error to watch out for